# Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.GameObject[]' to `UnityEngine.GameObject'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get the error on:

```
lad = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Ladder");
```

I'm just trying to disable all the ladders in the scene while the alarm is on and then enable them again once the alarm goes away. I'm not sure what the error means but need it fixed as soon as possible. I'm using C# and Unity 5.
 Thanks for any help you guys can provide!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LevelAlarm : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool alarmOn       = false;
    public bool bPlayerHidden = false;

    // How long an alarm lasts for
    [SerializeField]
    private float alarmTimer = 5.0f;

    private float alarmCurrentTimer = 0.0f;


    public GameObject lad;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        lad = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Ladder");


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        // While alarm is on, run a timer
        if (alarmOn) 
        {
            alarmCurrentTimer += Time.deltaTime;

            lad.SetActive(false);

            // Timer is complete, alarm resets
            if(alarmCurrentTimer >= alarmTimer)
            {
                alarmOn = false;
                alarmCurrentTimer = 0.0f;

                lad.SetActive(true);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag()` returns an array of `GameObjects`, if you want first object of this array, use this:

```
void Start () 
{
     var objects =  GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Ladder");
     if(objects != null && objects.Length > 0)
     {
         lad = objects[0];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag`, not `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag`, don't has character *"s"* after *"Object"*.

Answer (score 0):

Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.GameObject[]' to`UnityEngine.GameObject'
This error simply means that you try to stop alarm whose tag are "Ladder".It creates an array and the function you use accept only one element of utilityEngine.GameObject. So you may use foreach loop to access all elements in the array by using :

```
public bool alarmOn       = false;
public bool bPlayerHidden = false;

// How long an alarm lasts for
[SerializeField]
private float alarmTimer = 5.0f;

private float alarmCurrentTimer = 0.0f;


**public GameObject[] lad;**

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    lad = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Ladder");


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    // While alarm is on, run a timer
    if (alarmOn) 
    {
        alarmCurrentTimer += Time.deltaTime;
**foreach(var eachLad in lad)
{
eachLad.SetActive(false);
}**


        // Timer is complete, alarm resets
        if(alarmCurrentTimer >= alarmTimer)
        {
            alarmOn = false;
            alarmCurrentTimer = 0.0f;
**foreach(var eachLad in lad)
{
           eachLad.SetActive(true);
}**

        }
    }

}
```